# Showing images with data in datagridview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Can we bind the image column from a different source and the other columns from the datatable?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GridViewProducts" Margin="80,30,0,0" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="True" BorderThickness="12" 
            BorderBrush="PaleTurquoise" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="200" 
             Width="745" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" MouseEnter="GridViewProducts_MouseEnter" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn DisplayIndex="0" 
                          x:Name="imageColumn">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image x:Name="image_Grid_Column" 
                                      Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620654/7840702
This was the solution for me :)